# can't pass default comparer as IComparer<object>

Tags: c#, generics, llblgenpro

I'm trying to call a "Sort" method that expects a parameter of type `IComparer<object>`, using the code:

```
collection.Sort((IComparer<object>)Comparer<DateTime>.Default)
```

It builds but at run time I get an InvalidCastException with the message:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'System.Collections.Generic.GenericComparer`1[System.DateTime]'
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1[System.Object]'.
```

Now what?

Comment: Please post the declaration of "collection".  We need more information to help.

Comment: It is an LLBL collection, namely SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.EntityCollectionBase2<TEntity> (now you are sorry you asked :)

Comment: You'll need a custom comparer - if the types are always DateTIme values, what I just added should work (with only 5 extra lines of code)

Comment: ... also, no, this won't work in C# 4.0 either (because, while `IComparer<T>` will be contravariant, it won't be covariant - and this code tries to treat it as covariant).

Comment: @Pavel: And also because DateTime is a value type, and variance only works over reference types :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want is the default comparison, this will work:

```
collection.Sort(Comparer<object>.Default)
```

Comparer.Default uses your objects' inherent comparison semantics (i.e., IComparable.CompareTo).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you need to have a comparer of the appropriate type.

You could make a custom `IComparer<object>` class that just wrapped the DateTime comparer, but there is no way to do this directly via a cast.

If your collection always contains DateTime objects, then you can just do:

```
ICollection<DateTime> collection = ...;
collection.Sort(Comparer<DateTime>.Default); // or just collection.Sort()
```

---

Edit after reading the comment:

If you're working with an ICollection directly, you may want to use the LINQ option to do:

```
collection.Cast<DateTime>().OrderBy( date => date );
```

If you're working with something that implements `IList<T>`, (such as `List<DateTime>`) you can just call Sort() on the list itself.

---

Since you're using a non-standard class, you'll need to make your own comparer:

```
class Comparer : IComparer<object> {
    int Compare(object a, object b) {
         return DateTime.Compare((DateTime)a, (DateTime)b);
    }
}
```

You can then call:

```
collection.Sort(new Comparer() );
```

Comment: I got: 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Sort' and no extension method 'Sort' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The LINQ option won't work because I want an "in-memory" sort (LINQ OrderBy returns a new collection).  And as for the second suggestion, no it doesn't implement IList<T> :(

Comment: What type is your collection?  Can you put its declaration in place?

Comment: Edited again, since we know the collection type.

Comment: Hooray for co and contra variance in C# 4.0!

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the type of the collection object (i.e. to an `ArrayList` from a `List<object>`), then you can just use the non-generic `IComparer` interface (which `Comparer<DateTime>.Default` implements).

If you can't change the type of the collection object, then you are out of luck.
(You could always implement an object that implements `IComparer<object>`, like so:

```
 public class DateTimeComparer : IComparer<object>
    {       
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            IComparer myComparer = Comparer<DateTime>.Default as IComparer;
            return myComparer.Compare(x, y);
        }     
    }
```

(This will throw an exception if you have any non-DateTime items in your collection though)

EDIT:

You could also implement something a little bit more type safe, i.e.:

```
  public class DateTimeComparer : IComparer<object>
    {       
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            if ( x is DateTime && y is DateTime )
            {
                return Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare((DateTime) x, (DateTime) y);
            }
            else
            {
                // handle the type mismatch
            }
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define an extension function like this:

```
public static class ComparerConversion
    {
        private class ComparerWrapper<T> : IComparer<object>
        {
            private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;

            public ComparerWrapper(IComparer<T> comparer)
            {
                this.comparer = comparer;
            }

            public int Compare(object x, object y)
            {
                return this.comparer.Compare((T)x, (T)y);
            }
        }

        public static IComparer<object> ToObjectComparer<T>(this IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            return new ComparerWrapper<T>(comparer);
        }
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
List<object> collection = new List<object> { DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now };
collection.Sort(Comparer<DateTime>.Default.ToObjectComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to remove the cast and let the compiler to chose `IComparer` instead of `IComparer<T>`.

`Comparer<T>` implements both `IComparer<T>` and `IComparer` so it should work.

This works just fine:

```
ArrayList collection = new ArrayList {DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now};
collection.Sort(Comparer<DateTime>.Default);
```

Comment: I get: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<System.DateTime>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<object>

Comment: Are you trying to use a Sort function that has this Sort(IComparer<T> comparer>) signature or Sort(IComparer comparer)?

What is the type of your collection?

Comment: it expects IComparer<object>.  It is an LLBL collection, namely SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.EntityCollectionBase2<TEntity> (now you are sorry you asked :)

Comment: Than your only option is to create the wrapper